# astra_launch and astra_camera packages. Problems with RGB

Tags: ros, driver, topics

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all;

I have recently purchased an Orbbec Astra Pro sensor as a substitute for the difficult to get Asus Xtion Pro Live.
I have installed astra_launch and astra_camera packages. As the sensor was not recognized, I have also run the install.sh script from the astra_camera source code in GitHub.

Now, when I run the sensor with `roslaunch astra_launch astra.launch` the sensor is recognized and in Rviz, I can see depth images, ir_images and pointclouds, but I do not receive RGB images.
The topics corresponding to the RGB images are present, but they are not publishing anything.

Is this problem known? Any way to solve it?

I would appreciate any kind of advise or help...

Best regards,

Alberto

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/246595/astra_launch-and-astra_camera-packages.-problems-with-rgb./) by [altella](https://answers.ros.org/users/4898/altella/) on ROS Answers with karma: 149 on 2016-10-27

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jljess01](https://answers.ros.org/users/28960/jljess01/) on 2017-01-04**:
Just purchased a Turtlebot 2 from Clearpath Robotics.  It came with the Astra sensor installed.  However, I too am having trouble with RGB images as described above.

When I use image_view I do not have an rgb image available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I had the same issue as astra pro is what came with my Turtlebot 2 that I ordered from Clearpath Robotics.

My setup: Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS running ROS Indigo

The launch package that allowed me to have both depth and rgb is astra_pro.launch found here:  https://github.com/clearpathrobotics/ros_astra_launch/tree/upstream/launch

The help at clearpath was superb! Directions I received are as follows(You can edit the directories as you wish of course):

```
mkdir -p turtlebot_ws/src
cd turtlebot_ws/src
catkin_init_ws
git clone https://github.com/tonybaltovski/ros_astra_launch.git --branch upstream
git clone https://github.com/tonybaltovski/ros_astra_camera.git --branch upstream
cd ..
rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro=indigo -y
catkin_make
source devel/setup.bash
rosrun astra_camera create_udev_rules
(you may need to reboot here)
roslaunch astra_launch astra_pro.launch
```

---

Originally posted by [surfertas](https://answers.ros.org/users/27828/surfertas/) with karma: 265 on 2017-05-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [surfertas](https://answers.ros.org/users/27828/surfertas/) on 2017-05-03**:
In order for RViz to successfully subscribe to the RGB image topic, you need to take further steps to calibrate your camera, and generate a yaml file. Ive tried to document the steps here http://surfertas.github.io/rviz/turtlebot/2017/05/03/turtlebot-astrapro.html.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You probably bought an "Astra Pro" camera, not a regular "Astra". The Astra Pro camera doesn't have an RGB camera that's integrated with OpenNI2. Instead, it has a regular Video4Linux webcam. This means that from ROS's point of view, there are two completely separate devices: One OpenNI2 depth camera without RGB (that's launched via `astra.launch`), and one V4L camera (you can use the [usb_cam](http://wiki.ros.org/usb_cam) ROS driver for this).

This is the output of an Astra Pro:

```
$ lsusb
[...]
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 2bc5:0403  
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 2bc5:0501  
[...]
```

The `2bc5:0403` device is the OpenNI2 depth camera, the `2bc5:0501` device is the regular Video4Linux/UVC RGB webcam.

---

Originally posted by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) with karma: 11816 on 2017-01-23

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2